# dict does not contain the expected number of items

Tags: python, dictionary, iteration

I'm writing a program to iterate through a long number, converting it into a string, and then using an index list to pick out 10 individual consecutive numbers from the long number, then multiplying those ten numbers together and adding the numbers and the result to a dictionary. Then I am increasing the index list values by 1, and repeating the process until I have run through the whole number.

Then I am trying to find the largest value in the dictionary, and have the program tell me that value.

The problem I am having is that I have an error checking mechanism in the program, which tells me how many key/value pairs I have in the dictionary. It should be 990, but instead I have 53.

If anyone can identify what the problem is, I will be eternally grateful.

Code to follow:

```
from functools import reduce

#define the number to test
testno = 7316717653133062491922511967442657474235534919493496983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843858615607891129494954595017379583319528532088055111254069874715852386305071569329096329522744304355766896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113622298934233803081353362766142828064444866452387493035890729629049156044077239071381051585930796086670172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776657273330010533678812202354218097512545405947522435258490771167055601360483958644670632441572215539753697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482839722413756570560574902614079729686524145351004748216637048440319989000889524345065854122758866688116427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586178664583591245665294765456828489128831426076900422421902267105562632111110937054421750694165896040807198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188845801561660979191338754992005240636899125607176060588611646710940507754100225698315520005593572972571636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450

#declare initial variables
index=[]
products = {}
count = 0

#define functions
def product(x):
    return reduce((lambda a,b: a*b),x)

def increm(y):
    return [x+1 for x in y]

#def runproduct(x):
#    return product

def testnos(x):
    return [int(str(x)[y]) for y in index]

#define the initial index
for x in range(10):
    index = index+[x]

runtime = len(str(testno))-10

#start the while loop
while count < runtime:
    products[str(testnos(testno))] = product(testnos(testno))
    index = increm(index)
    count+=1

print("[+] Number of results: "+str(len(str(products.values))))
print("[+] The numbers with the largest product are: "+str(max(products.keys(),key=(lambda k:products[k]))))
```

Comment: (Just edited title for the OP - feel free to improve it though)

Comment: Perfect, thank you. Half the problem was not even knowing how to describe the problem.

Comment: You might just have a problem with your print function. `len(str(products.values))` just gives you the length of the string "'<built-in method values of dict object at 0x0000000002A67598>'" or something similar. Did you mean to write `print("[+] Number of results: "+str(len(products.values())))`?

Comment: @Kevin: or simpler still `str(len(products))` as the length of the dictionary will not change vis-a-vis the number of values..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a problem in your first `print` statement. You are currently converting your `products` into a string, which returns to you something like this

```
{'[0, 8, 1, 3, 5, 3, 3, 6, 2, 7]': 0, ..., '[7, 8, 4, 6, 8, 6, 2, 2, 4, 8]': 8257536}
```

Applying the `len` built-in over it will return the result **53**. What you really want here is calling `len` directly over you `products` variable.

```
>>> print("[+] Number of results: {}".format(len(products)))
[+] Number of results: 990
```

Consider using the `format` function when building your string. You can use [PyFormat website](http://pyformat.info/) as reference.